# Harry Potter fanfic: Draco asks Harry to take care of his daughter after her mother has been killed in a Death Eater raid

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

Involves Harry being at Privet Drive when he goes into his room he finds an intruder who happens to be Draco Malfoy; he is holding his daughter and asks Harry to take care of her. He leaves and at some point even brings Narcissa to stay with Harry.

You find out that the mother of Draco's daughter was murdered in a Death Eater raid and Draco barely got his daughter to Harry in time. Harry and Draco end up together at some point in the fic and Harry wants to stay and help raise Draco's daughter together.

Answer (score 1):

There's a strong chance this is [Secrets by Vorbiza](https://archiveofourown.org/works/8184311):

1. Draco shows up at Privet Drive wearing the death eater outfit, and dumps a baby in Harry's arms saying he doesn't know who else to turn to for help.  He immediately leaves.
2. He returns many hours later and explains the child is his; the mother was killed during a death eater raid that Draco had to participate in, and he managed to sneak the child away.
3. For reasons I don't remember, at one point, Draco, Narcissa, the baby, Harry, Winky, Hedwig and Fawkes all end up living in Harry's room at Privet Drive for a while.  I think they eventually move to Grimmauld Place, and I'm sure Snape is brought into the group at some point too.  I'm pretty sure it ends up being mild Drarry.